# Script Color Profiles To Normalize Color Across Multiple Scanners

Tags: image, algorithm, colors, compare, photoshop

A community project I volunteer for works to create high resolution images of collectible trading cards. The cards are scanned by other contributors, using scanners with varied makes, models, and color bias.

I need an algorithm which compares a platen of cards from one scanner to an identical platen of cards (a color target) from a second scanner, to create a color profile which normalizes the color bias in the first scanner. The profiles should consist of manually recordable photoshop adjustment settings.

I.E.

```
Hue/Sat Adjustment | Red , Hue +5 , Sat -10
Levels Adjustment | Black Point , 10
```

I can work in PHP or Javascript.

In my first attempt, I converted every pixel in a scan to HSB, and sorted the results into arrays of Red, Yellow, Green, Cyan, Blue, and Magenta. I then averaged the color groups and calculated the difference between the scans. I created a Photoshop hue/sat adjustment using the differential hue and saturation amounts on the bad scan. The result was not nearly accurate enough.

What specific process should I be using to compare the scans to create these color profiles?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't just take averages of the entire image, you must identify areas in each image that should match and take averages of those.

Comment: Which is why I was averaging each color range individually - then adjusting them individually. If I can't blanket compare channels or color ranges, this may be over my head.

Comment: Just as an experiment, segment your test images into those color groupings you described, and replace every pixel with the color grouping it falls into. I think you'll be surprised at the result.

Answer (score 1):

1.I do not think that HSV is the way

- all **common use** scanners/cameras I know scan R,G,B via band-pass filters
- so you have to manage R,G,B (most likely separately) not entire color space as whole
- use RGB space instead !!!

2.normalization

- you have to obtain transmit function for each color band (R,G,B)
- and obtain from it polynomial (saturation,brightness,gama correction)
- usually this for each band is enough:

  ```
  R(ir) = R0 + R1*ir + R2*ir*ir
  G(ig) = G0 + G1*ig + G2*ig*ig
  B(ib) = B0 + B1*ib + B2*ib*ib
  ```
- R,G,B is unnormalized image color
- ir,ig,ib is corresponding color in normalized image
- to obtain constants R(0,1,2),G(0,1,2),B(0,1,2)

  - scan some test image (like the border for card ...)
  - locate R,G,B gradients there (on reference scanner is the color ir,ig,ib)
  - and on normalized scanner take colors from the same positions (R(ir),G(ig),B(ib))
- now just create table for conversion  R -> ir , G -> ig , B -> ib for each scanner
- or create inverted transmit function
- and convert all images to normalized intensities

If the test image is not the same for all cards

- card border can vary from card to card
- not just in color but in positions
- then you have to adjust that by search the correct area in test image...